# How do I addClass once my animation has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add a CSS class at the end of an animation. Here I have a basic animation which moves the `div` with class `box`, adds border radius and changes the background color. At the end of this I want to add a class called `changecolor`. Everything works except the class gets added when the `div` `box` gets clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $('.box');
    e.click(function() {
        e.animate({left: '200px'}, 2000);
        e.animate({borderRadius: '100px'}, 2000);
        e.animate({backgroundColor: '#22222'}, 1000);
        e.addClass('changecolor');
    });
});
```

This my CSS. The `changecolor` div is just an example. I am not trying to achieve just a color change. I want to be able to add a different class to box at the end of my animation or maybe during the animation.

```
.box {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#A3D900
}
.change {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Everything works including adding the class but I want the class to be added at the end of the animation.

Comment: I believe you can answer this yourself after having a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
 e.animate({backgroundColor:'#22222'},1000, function() {
    e.addClass('changecolor');
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Simply adding [`complete` callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete).

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/x27Ar/1/

Comment: @user2375807 ;) great! and now press "V" under the vote buttons on the left side